# simplified _resample_ algorithm in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, resize, sampling

I am generating a variable size rows of samples from a DSP algorithm.
I mean each of the row contains random number of elements(Well, depending on the input).

I would like to resize into a specific number of samples per row.

Ex: column count in each row: 15 24 41 09 27
Say I would like to make it 30 element in a row.

Each of the row is a digitized curve samples.
I'm interested in making it contain equisized sample elements.

Comment: i miss the criterion of rows resizing

Comment: any interpolation method will work fine. Just like a image resizing. By the way, each row corresponds to a digitized continous curve.

Comment: you mean (in your example) to stretch 15 values to 30, 24 to 30, 41 to 30, etc.?

Comment: yes, while reducing the damage to the original curve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to *resample* your row values, the idea is roughly like this:

1. interpolate each row to a continuous curve
2. quantize each curve to a fixed number of values (30)

Obviously, for row with >30 values, you will lose some information.

Comment: Function _resample_ is a computational intensive. I am looking for stripped down algorithm for embedded system application.